# What is the best way to add Jquery to my drupal site without building modules and keeping it cut and paste?

Tags: javascript

I see some very nice effect on http://www.jqueryscript.net/  and I would like to add some of these to my drupal site.

Can I just cut and paste the code in content or blocks to make this work?

I'm sure I can, but before I get into an adventure, I would like to do this the right way.